# Error Code: MD1000 when directing Seller accounts to authorize [Amazon, SP-API, Website]

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

My object is handling multiple sellers to authorize me to use their data. So I need their token.

I followed the: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/website-authorization-workflow

but no matter what I try it gives me

[image: this error]

Made an anchor link to navigate them to this link

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/apps/authorize/consent?application_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.???????????&version=beta

after login, the page returns unable to find application Error Code: 1000, instead of click to authorize content.

Answer (score 0):

> https://sellercentral.amazon.com/apps/authorize/consent?application_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.???????????&version=beta

You're passing a client id in `application_id` param, instead of application id.

You can find it in the Developer Application List, below the Application Name.
And An Application ID start with `amzn1.sp.solution`.